# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000 and 3009)

Tags: errors, captions, overleaf

I get an error of underfull badness 10000 and 3009 in the caption of a figure and cannot find out why. This is what I write in the caption:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/gis image.png}
    \caption{1,2 and 3 $\sigma$ ellipses. Background image (HMC\_11W14\_nd5) in QGIS. Available HiRISE digital terrain models (DTMs): DTEEC\_004935\_1965\_004494\_1986\_L01, DTEEC\_009345\_1935\_003454\_1995\_L01, DTEEC\_346425\_1965\_035358\_1965\_L01, DTEEC\_037070\_1935\_034323\_1995\_L01, DTEEC\_034599\_1965\_023567\_1965\_L01, DTEEC\_045355\_1935\_053962\_1995\_L01, ExoArgyre\_7\_ABEE\_1m.}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  From what you've shown (which is not *nearly* enough to debug from), I suspect the log from trying to process this has a lot more errors than the warnings about underfull badness!  Since the underscore is defined to initiate s subscript in math mode, there should be at least one error saying that math mode is required, and the output (if any) will be very strange looking.  Help us to help you, and wrap this in a small, compilable example that shows the document class and relevant packages; the example should go from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you for the comment, I will fix it to my next questions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's essentially impossible to typeset in a decent way such a caption.

I suggest to use a shorter caption and to add the data about the images outside it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}

\caption{1, 2 and 3 $\sigma$ ellipses.}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Background image (HMC\_11W14\_nd5) in QGIS. \\
  Available HiRISE digital terrain models (DTMs): \\
  DTEEC\_004935\_1965\_004494\_1986\_L01, \\
  DTEEC\_009345\_1935\_003454\_1995\_L01, \\
  DTEEC\_346425\_1965\_035358\_1965\_L01, \\
  DTEEC\_037070\_1935\_034323\_1995\_L01, \\
  DTEEC\_034599\_1965\_023567\_1965\_L01, \\
  DTEEC\_045355\_1935\_053962\_1995\_L01, \\
  ExoArgyre\_7\_ABEE\_1m.
\end{tabular}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me!